# "Operand data type text is invalid for min operator" SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I am getting this error "Operand data type text is invalid for min operator" when trying to run this code

```
Select
UserID,
min(Description)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UserID
```

I have tried

```
select min(cast(AttributeValue as varchar(max)))
```

But i couldnt get it working.

Is there any way around this? Thanks

Comment: `varchar(min)`? I know you're going for a `MIN` aggregate, but even so it's still `varchar(max)`. (The `max` here just means "bigly big string", like `text` once used to, and does not vary based on what operator you're applying.)

Comment: The error is giving you the answer here. The `text` datatype has been deprecated for a long time now. You should be using `varchar(max)`. Thus, you're query would be : `SELECT MIND(CAST(AttributeValue AS varchar(MAX)));`. Expect awful performance, however.

Comment: *IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.*: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

Comment: What is the _MINIMUM_ value for a blob of text?

Comment: MIN can be used with numeric, char, varchar, uniqueidentifier, or datetime columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
Select UserID,min(CAST(Description AS VARCHAR(50)))
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

"Min" function not worked with "group by". So, please try with:

```
Select UserID   
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UserID
```